# backbone router not working without # in the URL

Tags: html, google-app-engine, requirejs, app.yaml, backbone-layout-manager

I am using backbone layoutmanager, handlebars and requirejs for my application with HtML5 and its a single page application. I am using `backbone.history.start({ pushState:true })` which is helping in getting rid of # if I type URL as localhost:9090/#abc but if I paste the URL localhost:9090/abc in browser then its not routing to the correct page but its going to the routes in app.yaml.

On click event I am able to navigate to URL localhost:9090/abc,but not when I copy-paste in browser directly.

I have done a lot of research to solve the issue but no results. Any suggestion will be helpful.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you should read about the `#` in url - the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). To put it simply: everything before the `#` is routed on server, and everything after the `#` is routed in javascript on browser.

So when you call `localhost:9090/#abc` the server look for resources on `/`, which I guess is your JS app and returns it to browser. Browser then executes JS app, which in turn checks the identifier after `#` and decides what to display.

Also I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to do - are you trying to get rid of `#` yet at the same time have history support in JS app? Afaik this can not be done.